# how to convert "foobar?" into 'foobar?

Tags: string, symbols

I'm trying to turn a string containing a question mark into the corresponding symbol but:

`(intern "foobar?")` returns `'foobar\?`

How can i do the same thing without the backslash?

Also i'm interested about why `foobarp` is prefered to `foobar?` in elisp code

Comment: The `p` (or `-p` with `multi-word-names`) suffix for predicates is simply a convention; and when there's a convention, it's preferable that people stick to it for the sake of consistency.  The `?` suffix is a Scheme convention, I believe.

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp)Coding Conventions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Symbol Type`

> In contrast to its use in strings, however, a backslash in the name
>   of a symbol simply quotes the single character that follows the
>   backslash.  For example, in a string, ‘\t’ represents a tab
>   character; in the name of a symbol, however, ‘\t’ merely quotes the
>   letter ‘t’.

So the symbol `foobar\?` *is* in fact exactly what you asked for.

If you evaluate `'foobar?` you will see the same thing.

Note that, as always, what you're seeing is the *printed representation* of the returned value.

The slightly curious thing is that, as detailed in that info node (and indeed demonstrated by evaluating `'foobar?`), `?` does not *need* to be escaped in symbol names.  Evidentially Emacs is choosing to print it that way, but I couldn't tell you why that is.

```
(symbol-name (intern "foobar?"))
=> "foobar?"
```